# Can I change the name of the world or character?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Is it possible to change the name of your character or world on Terraria on iOS? If so please tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

It takes root access for Android or iFunbox for iOS. Find your world save data with any valid and working hex editor. The start of the file will have your title filled in.

For instance, if the world is called "Castle", the title will appear as `C a s t l e`. Just change the letter every other value starting from "C".

If you try simply renaming the world, it will clone the original world. To illustrate, if my world is "Castle", and I rename the file to "Main World", when I play and save on "Main World", "Main" will stay as if never touched, but the world played will be Castle. If you have the altered "Castle" and "Main", saving on "Main" will overwrite the Castle save file.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! I hope [the edit I've made](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/198825/revisions) has made the answer better while retaining what you were trying to say. If I've inadvertently changed the meaning of your answer, please don't hesitate to edit the answer again using the edit button under the answer. Thank you!

Comment: How interesting. My homeworld **is** called Castle :P